# call a server side python script from javascript

Tags: javascript, python

how to call a server side python script from javascript. if test.py is the python script file in server, and if the parameter to be passed to python is another url , then how this can be executed from javascript, how the return string from python script is obtained to the javascript.

Answer (score 3):

You can directly call the python script from javascript. You need to use an appropriate server-side technology (asp.net, php, servlet). The best solution will be to create a REST service, by defining a URL, which when called (through ajax for example) will execute the python script and write the output to the body of the request. This will be easier if you are using [django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) or another python web framework.